# Instruments UI Automation tests for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, testing, user-interface, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I'm a newbie in UI Automation using instruments and I have the following question:
 - the application starts and I get the mainWindow screen (which contains SignIn and Register buttons) 
 - I've managed to write the JavaScript code in order to tap one of the two buttons.
 -> after tapping one of the buttons, another screen is displayed. let's say the Sign In screen which contains two fields: username and password.

In this case, how can I tell Instruments that this is another screen and this contains another elements that should be retrieved in order to fill the fields and tap the Sign In button ?

I only know to retrieve the mainWindow. I don't know how to write the code for a next screen

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to capture what you do with the small record button in the Javascript editor window? That way you can find out how Instruments can call the elements you use.

See also this thread:

[UI Automation - how to capture - record using javascript editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815765/ui-automation-how-to-capture-record-using-javascript-editor)